# Not able to install Ubuntu on Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 machine. The initial installation finished, when I was then given the option to restart the machine to complete installation.

After restarting it says "Starting Ubuntu". After that the system does not show any messages or options to proceed with the installation.

How can I get the installation to complete?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu (eg Ubuntu 10.04.1 Desktop, 64 bit)?

Answer (score 0):

When the machine starts it should give you a DOS like window with the option to choose from several boot options one of which is a 'ubuntu safemode' though it may be worded differently.   Try this or one of the other boot options and it may sort the problem.

Comment: `DOS-like window` is a contradiction in adjecto. Better say `text screen`.

Comment: @user: Many MS-DOS programs [had windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface#TUI_under_MS-DOS_and_Microsoft_Windows), and some of them used graphical VGA modes, too. I agree that "text screen" is a better term, though.

Comment: To *have* a window is not the same as to *be* a DOS-like window. DOS was an OS (hence D**OS**). On DOS, they were called frames, or boxes, not windows, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

One More option is using VMware from inside Windows 7, it is much better option, as if you want to delete your Ubuntu partition in the future, you would not have to re partition your drive space to regain control of it. More over Ubuntu from inside VMware just runs like any other application.

So I suggest try VMWare it saves much of the hassle or simply use LiveCD option if your work is temporary.